# NGINX Ubuntu Web Server accesing CentOS file server: forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, centos

basically i have my front on ubuntu but i get the files from a file server in CentOS.

I tried `chmod 777` of the folder NGINX needs to access which is where the site files are, and tried running nginx as root too.

I saw that user id's are different in ubuntu and centOS and that even after running as root, i would still get 403. Tailed the log and this is the result:

```
2018/03/17 08:44:12 [error] 103557#103557: *3 directory index of
"/xxxxxxxx/" is forbidden, client: xxx, server: xx, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx"
```

Does it have to do with the servers having a different OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It happening because action "directory listing" is denied by your server configuration.**
When you sending request to the nginx, server executes next sequence of actions:

- pulls the names of default files for requested directory. For this purposes you have next line in your server configuration:

  `index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;`
- If one of those files are exists in requested directory it will returned to user.
- If no one of those files are present in requested directory or if you haven`t defined this directive in your configuration, nginx will try to retrieve and return  to user the list of files in requested directory. But            action "directory listing" by default is denied in nginx configuration. To allow it you should to add the next line to your config:

  ```
  location /somedir {
         autoindex on;
  }
  ```

  If action "directory listing" is denied and no one of default fies are present in requested directory, you will receive 403 Forbidden.